# Check Outlook 2010 VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, automation, outlook-2010

I'm still stumped on this same project that I've been working on for about a week.  I think I've got the VBA worked out, but I've only ever used VBA modestly in Access.  This is my first go around at trying to create a procedure in Outlook 2010.  Ultimately, my goal is to check incoming emails to see if they have attachments.  If they do have attachments, check to see if the file type is .xlsx.  If the attachment is a spreadsheet, I would like to write the senders email address to a table called **tblOutlookLog** in an Access DB called **MSOutlook.ACCDB**.  Whenever you have a chance, can you please look over this code and let me know what I'm doing wrong or if there is a more efficient was to accomodate what I'm trying to accomplish?  Whenever Outlook opens, I receive an error highlighting the line **Set db = OpenDatabase(strdbPath & strdbName)** and the error says **Unrecognized Database format**.I appreciate any help in advance.  Thank you once again!!

```
  Option Explicit

Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olAtmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset

    Const strdbPath = "\\FMI-FS\Users\sharp-c\Desktop\"
    Const strdbName = "MSOutlook.accdb"
    Const strTableName = "tblOutlookLog"

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(strdbPath & strdbName)
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strTableName, dbOpenDynaset)
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    db.Close
    Set olns = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub olInbox_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olAtmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim rec As Recipient
    Dim strFoldername As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    For Each olItem In olInbox.Items
      For Each olAtmt In olItem.Attachments
        If olItem.olAtmt.Count > 0 Then
            If Right$(olAtmt.FileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
                strFilename = "\\FMI-FS\Users\sharp-c\Desktop\Test" & olAtmt.FileName
                olAtmt.SaveAsFile strFilename
                i = i + 1
                If Item.Class = olMail Then
                    Set olItem = Item
                    With olItem
                            rst.AddNew
                            rst!Subject = Left(olItem.Subject, 255)
                            rst!Sender = olItem.Sender
                            rst!FromAddress = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
                            rst!Status = "Inbox"
                            rst!Logged = olItem.ReceivedTime
                            rst!AttachmentPath = strFilename
                            For Each rec In olItem.Recipients
                                rst!To = rst!To & rec.Name & " : " & rec.Address & ";"
                            Next
                            rst.Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If

         Next olAtmt
         Next olItem

        Set olAtmt = Nothing
        Set olItem = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473445/outlook-2010-vba-invalid-or-unqualified-reference and you have not said where you are getting the problem.

Comment: Can you open the database manually? Have you tried `Dim db As DAO.database`? Have you a reference to Microsoft Data Access Components library?

Comment: I added the Dim db as DAO.database and I still get the same error.  Would there be any type of conflict if you added references to both MS Access 14 Object Library and MS DAO 3.6 Object Library at the same time?

Comment: That should have been Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library and you should not be using MS DAO 3.6 with accdb. You did not say whether it is possible to open the db manually.

Comment: Whenever I remove the reference for MS DAO 3.6, the 'DIM db as Database' or 'DIM db as DAO.database' line gives me the error **User Defined Type Not Defined**.  Yes, I can open the database manually without a problem.

Comment: Yes, it would if you do not have a reference to  Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library instead.

Comment: Remou, I unloaded both DAO 3.6 and MS Access 14.0 references, saved the project, closed and reopened Outlook and now the connection to the looks like it's established whenever I open Outlook, but I emailed myself a spreadsheet and no data is being written to the tbl.  I think there may be another issues with my code in the `Private Sub olInbox_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)` sub.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8316/discussion-between-remou-and-csharp821)

Answer (score 0):

Hi l think what you need is these extra lines

*Dim wks as DAO.Workspace*

*Set wks = Workspaces(0)*

Then change following line

Set db = OpenDatabase(strdbPath & strdbName)

to

*Set db = **wks**.OpenDatabase(strdbPath & strdbName)*

This is based on what l found a dog eared book l have called 'DAO object Model'  I'm sure this is code l have used before however l don't have time to find the projects l used them in.

Also have a look at http://www.helenfeddema.com/CodeSamples.htm l checked there as well.  Helen know Access and DAO very well, she uses a slightly different method to connect to a remote access DB however its worth having a look.

Comment: No, you don't, you just need the right library for .accdb, Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library

Comment: has that changed in Access 2010?

Comment: The DAO library has changed since 2007, AFAIK.